# Where do you place the word 'only'

Tags: word-order, only

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct position of “only”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/correct-position-of-only)
>   [Use of “only” and word-order](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10297/use-of-only-and-word-order)

Should one say

> The bidders shall not be permitted to bid for one or two tenders only.

or

> The bidders shall not be permitted to bid for only one or two tenders.

Answer (score 5):

Both versions are normal English - *only* can shift around, to the extent that sometimes (not here) it may actually be ambiguous what exactly it modifies.

In common parlance people would probably place the word *only* immediately before *one or two*, if only because that particular numeric range is the primary focus of the word.

But OP's example being relatively formal (as indicated by the word *shall*), it's more likely to come at the end. The reader in such a context is expected to be capable of parsing *one or two tenders* as a complete syntactic unit modified by *only*.