# "It is just enough" or "It just is enough"?

Tags: word-usage

Where should I put the "Just" in a sentence? Before be or after be?

It is just enough.

or

It just is enough.

Comment: This depends on your intended meaning.  Please add more detail.

Comment: Related question, [Position of the word ‘just’](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217019/position-of-the-word-just) and [Proper grammar regarding “write only” or “only write”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47300/proper-grammar-regarding-write-only-or-only-write).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It is just enough" means that you have your exact requirement and nothing more than is required.

"It just is enough" means "It" alone is sufficient.

So you need to place the "just" based on your intended meaning.

Comment: What would be the difference between e.g. "Happiness is just enough" and "Happiness just is enough"? To me they sound the same, meaning e.g. that "happiness" alone is sufficient to live a good/happy life... Thank you!