# About using "only" with present perfect

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order, present-perfect

I have seen this sentence in a status from one of my facebook friends. It doesn't sound right to me.

> We have only left the city for the day.

I think that it should be something like:

> We have left the city for only a day (just for a day).

Which one is correct and what is the usage of *only* with present perfect? I consider sentences like

> We have only seen a few of the sights of this marvelous city.

to be correct, but the above sentence just doesn't sound correct for me.

Comment: The subtle difference seems to be that in the first instance, *only* rings of *hardly*, while in the second, it just states the period matter-of-fact, with no connotations.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct position of "only"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/correct-position-of-only)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Careful (not to say pedantic) speakers place 'only' directly in front of the word or phrase it qualifies. So they would say: "I drink only water." The claim is that saying: "I only drink water" could be interpreted as meaning: "Drinking is the only thing I do with water, not washing in it or playing with it, etc."

In theory there may indeed be cases where the placement of 'only' is a source of ambiguity. In practice, however, it is unlikely that anyone would be confused, particularly in spoken language where intonation contributes to meaning.

"We have only seen a few of the sights of this marvelous city" sounds perfectly natural to me, a native speaker. In fact Google returns 3 times as many hits for "I have only seen ..." as for "I have seen only ... ".

As an aside, the sentences are in the present, not past, perfect. But the tense of the statement is irrelevant to considerations of where 'only' should be placed.

Comment: I’ve always found *only* to be stronger as an adjective than as an adverb.  *I only have one.* vs *I have only one.*

Comment: @tchrist: Why should *have* be any different to, say, *like*? Contrast *"I only like you"* with *"I like only you"*, where strictly speaking the first should imply *"but I don't* **love** *you"*, whereas the second implies *"and no others"*.

Answer (score 3):

The placement of *only* has nothing to do with the present perfect construction, but with the placement of the **focus** NP that *only* binds. Here's what [McCawley](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/115157/15299) (p.68) says about it:

> There are a number of words in English (*only, even, too, also*) that are associated with a **focus:** an item that is implicitly contrasted with other items, as in *John drinks only beer,* where *only* serves to contrast *beer* with such other items as *wine, vodka,* and so on. *Only* usually precedes its focus, but need not **immediately** precede it; for example, *John only drinks beer* can be intrepreted with *beer* as focus even though *only* is separated from it by *drinks*.

Basically, the rule is that *only* must bind some focussed item (word, phrase, or clause) that comes after it. This focus must have primary stress (*He only drinks **beer***).

*Only* may appear

- **either** immediately before the focus,
- **or** immediately before the first word of a constituent that ***contains*** the focus.

The reason why *John only drinks beer* can be interpreted with *beer* as focus is because *drinks* is the first word in a Verb Phrase (*drinks beer*) that contains *beer*. It can also be interpreted with *drinks* as focus (as opposed to, say, *brews* or *sells*), or with the whole VP *drinks beer* as focus (as opposed to, say, *smokes pot* or *gambles*).

Answer (score 1):

*We have only left the city for the day* is the normal way of saying the speaker and the speaker’s companions are absent from the city for the day and for no longer. *We have left the city for only a day* means the same, but is probably found less frequently.