# How can I counteract the meaning of "only" changing due to verb modifier?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

How can I counteract the meaning of "only" changing due to verb modifier?

"Only" has a different meaning if there is a modifier to the verb.

I want to make "I only strive towards success," mean the same thing as "I only strive. This striving is towards success."

If "only" wasn't a tricky word then "I only strive towards success," would mean the exact same thing as "I only strive. This striving is towards success." However in reality, the first sentence means that I strive and this striving is exclusively towards success. But the first sentence does not necessarily mean that the only action I do is striving towards success. And the second sentences means what I wish the first sentence meant: "The only action I do is striving towards success."

My question is the following. How can "I only strive towards success," be changed to mean the second sentences?

Comment: “The only thing I do is strive toward success.”   Is that what you’re after?

Comment: @Jim Yes. Although I think it would be better to replace "the only thing I do is strive" with "my actions only are striving."

Comment: You are free to think whatever you like.

Comment: And in any case, why would you want to focus on just the verb "strive", rather than the whole VP?

Comment: @BillJ I don't think I only want to focus on the verb "strive." If your referring to my comment to Jim; I am not excluding the verb phrase. The full sentence would be, "My actions only are striving toward success."

Comment: @jxh What part of it means something I don't think it means?

Comment: @user235979: Sorry. How about *I only strive and only towards success.*

Comment: @jxh (1) You don't have to be sorry. If there is a part of it that means something I don't think it means, I would like to know what it is. (2) That doesn't seem grammatically correct. I don't think "and" can be used as a seperator between a verb and its modifier (the modifier being "only towards success").

Comment: @user235979: I realize I am being a bit liberal with the use of the conjunction, but I am reversing the order of the conditional phrase. So, if it were better for you: *Only towards success, I only strive.* The repetitive use of *only* is meant to clarify that it is being applied to both the action and the goal.

Comment: As I think more about what you are trying to say, it seems to be something like *I always try to succeed.*

Comment: If you remove the "toward success", what does "I only strive", on its own, actually mean? If you "only strive" does it mean you never eat, walk, sleep etc?

Comment: @WS2 Exactly. Why has it taken till now for someone to CV on 'lack of clarity' grounds?

Comment: Are you the only one to strive? I think not. Reminds me of the Liberty Insurance commercial: "Only pay for what you need" instead of "Pay for only what you need."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I see any difference between the meanings of

- *I only strive towards success.*
- *I only strive. This striving is towards success.*

But, since [*only* is a quantifier with a stressed focus element](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/115157/15299), if you want to make *strive* the focus, just **stress** it. Normally one would stress *success* as the focus of *only*, and stressing the last word in a sentence is a natural pattern, so that's almost the automatic interpretation.

> BTW, by ***stress***, I mean say it LOUDer (the first syllable of *louder* is stressed). English has several levels of stress, and most words have a stressed syllable; further, every sentence has words that are stressed or unstressed. This is why we're not often confused about what *only* means in speech; that only happens in writing, which doesn't represent stress.

Answer (score 0):

"I only strive towards success." -- ambiguous.

We mean
"(I only strive) (towards success)."

So it would be,
"I only strive, towards success." -- the comma removes all doubt, and serves just that purpose, being otherwise redundant.

Answer (score -1):

As with any adverb, the precise position of the adverb makes a difference: before/after the verb/verb phrase and before/after the clause/sentence.

As with most words, *only* has a variety of shades of meaning, and we see that in your sentence:

> I only strive towards success.

First there is one you mention: the only thing I strive for is success.
Then there is the broader sense: the only thing I do is strive for success.
Then there is an apologetic sense: I was only doing my best to succeed.
Then there is an alternation sense: Only I wasn't trying to fail but to succeed.

Generally language is ambiguous, and the longer and more complex the sentence the more ambiguous it tends to be. Sometimes the best way to clarify is by breaking the sentence up, or by following with a disambiguating phrase or sentence, as you have explored. Sometimes you can move the adverb or change the tense to clarify. Often you don't need to do anything because it is clear in context.

Consider these variants (not all of which sound natural with the verb phrase used) - you can match them against the four shades of meaning above (exercise for the reader, figure out the permutation and the logic):

> 1. Only I strive towards success.
> 2. I only strive towards success.
> 3. I strive only towards success.
> 4. I strive towards success only.

So the answer to the question is "move it": move the "only" to the place that gives the intended meaning!

Comment: This does provide helpful information. However it doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: The answer to the question, as encapsulated here, is to move it in relation to the verb and its modifier. Added as the final paragraph.