# Position of "only" in “We  have two possibilities”

Tags: adverb-position

Is there any difference in meaning between the three following sentences?

- We **only** have two possibilities.
- We have **only** two possibilities.
- We have two possibilities **only**.

I have already read
[Correct position of "only"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/correct-position-of-only#) and I know that the position of *only* and the emphasis (written or oral) may change the meaning of *some* sentences, but I am not sure if it does here.

Note: It is clear that “only we have two possibilities” has a different meaning. My question is restricted to the sentences I’ve listed above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since *only* (like *even, too,* and *also*) is a word with a [focussed constituent](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/115157/15299) elsewhere in the sentence, its placement has to coordinate with that focus. The rule for *only* is that it has to go

**either**

- immediately before the focussed constituent

**or**

- immediately before any constituent that contains the focussed constituent

**or**

- at the end of the focussed constituent (especially if that's the end of the sentence, too).

In this case, the verb phrase *have 2 choices* is a constituent that may be focussed, and so is the noun phrase *2 choices*, and so is the numeral *2*. There is no special difference in focussing on any of them in particular, but if the speaker wanted to distinguish (say) *2*, they could contrastively stress it. But this one provides for all senses, and -- because the structure is transparent -- also indicates that which sense one chooses doesn't matter.

And sentence (1) places the *only* before the verb phrase, thus making all interpretations available. Similarly, (2) focusses on either the *2* or *2 choices*, which is again not really a difference unless stressed, and (3) follows the final part of the rule; a comma is common but not required in this case.