# Why does the 'only' move?

Tags: grammar, speech

In conversational and spoken English, it's common to hear statements like

> I only answer phone calls from people I know.

The "correct" form of this would be

> I answer phone calls only from people I know.

In rare situations this can lead to ambiguity, but usually only in written
English; when speaking, emphasis and intonation clears all doubt about what is
'only'. For instance, someone might say

> You only run during the day.

Which of the possible meanings is intended could be clarified by adding more
information or by changing the position of 'only':

> (1) You only run during the day, but you also walk at night.
>   (2a) You run only during the day. *or*
>   (2b) You run during the day only.

It seems that 'only' moves only leftward, farther away from what it qualifies.
A similar thing happens with 'either'.

Is there some sort of explanation for this movement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [We only have 2 possibilities - position of "only"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507038/we-only-have-2-possibilities-position-of-only) PLEASE READ THE ANSWER THERE

Comment: @green_ideas It does indeed. Sorry for the duplicate; I missed that one when I was searching for similar questions.