# Is the usage of 'only' correct

Tags: only

> A: Why are you doing this?
>
> B: You **only** asked for this, didn't you?

Is the usage of *only* here correct so as to mean *you were the one who*?

Comment: I'd say "It's you who asked for this, isn't it?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct position of 'only'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/correct-position-of-only)? Or [When should 'only' come before a verb phrase?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/528839/when-should-only-come-before-a-verb-phrase)?  
 Actually, John Lawler's answer at [Position of "only" in “We  have two possibilities”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507038/position-of-only-in-we-have-two-possibilities) covers all bases.

Comment: No: if someone said that to me, I'd probably take it to mean "It was only this and nothing else that you asked for", where "this" is the focus. For the focus to be understood as "you", you'd need something like "It was only you who asked for this, wasn't it?"

Comment: @BillJ: For the focus to be understood as "you", you just need ***Only you...*** rather than ***You only...***

Comment: I don't think anyone would say "Only you asked for this, didn't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't correct. It would mean *All you did was ask for this*.

For the meaning you want it would be better to say

> You were the one who asked for this, weren't you?

In old-fashioned literary language, you could say

> You only are the one I love (meaning *only you*)

Comment: Is it different from ''You are the only one I love." 2) Can't we go without 'only', like "It was you who asked for it."

Comment: @RamPillai - It is different only because, as I said, it is 'literary' language, Yes, certainly we can say _It was you who asked for it, wasn't it?_