# “Only use” vs “use only”

Tags: grammar, word-order

Would one say they “typically **only use** public transportation” or “typically **use only** public transportation” inverting the order ?

This is to settle an argument between my friends.

Comment: What about 'typically use public transportation only'? Grammatically all are correct, though 'typically' next to 'only' is a bit clumsy.

Comment: Anyone saying one is wrong is wrong. The second variant is more formal, and it can be argued that the use of 'typically' sits better with the more formal variant. // Admittedly,  'typically only use public transportation' _does_ have the limiting modifier 'only' before the verb, but in this case 'only **_use_** as opposed to **_trainspot_**, _**hold up stagecoaches_** or **_photograph buses_** say' is hardly a likely reading. "He only eats fish" is standard to mean "He eats only fish".

Answer (score 3):

In speech, there is no problem. You can hear the focus constituent of *only* by its high stress, so [*only* can go immediately before any constituent that contains its focus](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/115157/15299). In this case, *only use p.t* or *use only p.t.* both work viva voce, no diff, speaker's choice.

But in writing, a reader can't hear the intonation that identifies the focus of *only* to a listener, so the writing rule is to put *only* right before its focus constituent, to eliminate ambiguity (assuming that's what you want to do with the writing). In written communication, *use only public transportation* is simpler and requires no syntactic processing.

Answer (score 2):

My Answer is basically a comment which is too long.

In a sentence "Only" can occur in various Positions, where each has a slightly Different meaning.

Consider:
I cook minced meat.

Insert "only" in various Positions, and check the meaning:
Only I cook minced meat : Nobody else in my house can cook that.
I only cook minced meat : I do not eat it.
I cook only minced meat : I can not cook other types of meat.
I cook minced only meat : Meaningless ? Not sure ; There may be something like "minced-only meat" versus "minced-and-marinated meat", which I can not cook.

Coming to your Question:
To me "I typically **only use** public transportation" might indicate that I **only use**, but do not support/promote/praise, public transportation.
While "I typically use **only public** transportation" might indicate that I do not use private transportation.

**Only you** [ nobody else ] can use this to settle the argument between friends.
You can **only use** [ involve no other action ] this to settle the argument between friends.
You can use **only this** [ use nothing else ] to settle the argument between friends.

**IMPORTANT**: Even though there are various meanings attached to the Positions of "Only", informally, the context in the conversation will let you know what was meant, even when "Only" was in a wrong Position.

Comment: No. 'I only cook minced meat' in conversation defaults to 'I don't cook any meat other than mince' (this will not have the stress on _cook_) on pragmatic grounds (how people actually use language); this is not 'using _only_ in a wrong position'. The 'correct' 'I cook only minced meat' sounds pretentious in most conversation. Rules are defined largely by usage, not out-of-date books on grammar.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I will take a random example and change it to suit my example : Don Knuth said "I have only proved it correct, not tried it." [[ https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth ]] ; I can change this to "I have only cooked it, not tried it." or even "I only cook it, never eat it." or " [ Being a Professional Chef, when someone orders it ] , I **only cook** the Damn minced meat ; I never eat it, because I hate that texture !! "

Comment: You say "Check the meaning" not @Check the meaning in a sentence where the 'rule-based' reading is forced. Pragmatics is at least as important as grammar.

Comment: Pragmatic Example : When someone tells me "All Politicians are **not** honest ; [....] Octogenarian Politicians are honest" ; I know what they mean, but it is "wrong" and the "correct" way would be "**Not** all Politicians are honest ; [....] Octogenarian Politicians are honest" .... [[ cont ]]

Comment: [[ cont ]] .... What I am trying to say : We can generally make out what someone wants to say, by pauses & stresses & intonations & even by common usages ; But there may be a "better" way to state it. In OP Example, Both are grammatically correct, Both go with the same meaning in given context, But may mean something else in other contexts, Hence, one way is "better" than the other, though while speaking informally they are fine. [[ PS :: I am not sure what you mean in your Previous Comment about "Check the meaning" where there might by a typo ]] @EdwinAshworth

Comment: You're arguing with McCawley (and John Lawler) here. '_Only_ usually precedes its focus, but need not immediately precede it; for example, _John only drinks beer_ can be interpreted with beer as focus even though only is separated from it by drinks.' In deciding that your way is 'better', you're electing _yourself_ as judge in this matter.

Comment: I am in agreement with Lawler, and have mentioned in my answer that "the context in the conversation will let you know what was meant" & Lawler mentioned "the writing rule is to put only right before its focus constituent" : Both ViewPoints are almost same except for Better Terminology by Lawler ; I said "context in conversation" whereas Lawler said "intonation & focus" .... [[cont ]]

Comment: [[cont]] .... Coming to McCawley, Obviously, he is talking about speech, not writing, when he says "Pronounced with stress on beer, the focus is beer", not covering the case where there is no stress; I do not have his book; Wonder what his ideas were, on writing "Only" in Various Positions. Yet, that too ties with my claim that "the context in the conversation will let you know what was meant" where the stress gives the outline. [[ @EdwinAshworth , this is my last comment because I am getting warning about "moving extended discussions to chat" ; Thanks for introducing McCawley ]]

Comment: But 'the context in the conversation will let you know what was meant, even when "Only" was in a wrong Position' asserts that there is rule-breaking even in speech. JL states, on the contrary, that the rule is a [to quote] 'writing [only] rule' and 'in speech ... _only_ can go immediately before any constituent that contains its focus'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you and your friends mean to say "I do not use any form of transportation other than public transportation", the correct answer is:

> typically use only public transportation

However, as the other answer points out, which of the two is correct depends on the intended meaning.

Comment: Are the many practised Anglophones who say "She only eats fish" rather than "She eats only fish" incorrect? Who has the authority to say so? McCawley, who studied under Chomsky, I believe, finds "She only eats fish" etc totally acceptable in conversation, not incorrect.

Comment: "She only eats fish" and "she eats only fish" are both correct, depending on what the speaker is trying to communicate. See the assumption made in the first sentence of my answer.

"She only eats fish" - Eating fish is the only thing she does.

"She eats only fish" - She eats nothing other than fish, but she does do other things.

Comment: And, I'd add, there is a difference between conversational English (looser) and written English (stricter adherence to grammar rules).

Comment: No. You're applying strict adherence to a rule-of-thumb and disregarding what most native speakers actually do. Pragmatics is extremely important. Many practised Anglophones would say "She only eats fish" with the meaning of the never-ambiguous "She eats only fish", meaning that the grammars must recognise this as correct usage. // If you're going to demand adherence to the written letter of laws, Grice's maxim of non-ambiguity would disallow "She only eats fish" itself ... Eating fish is the only thing she does? or All she does with fish is to eat them. _I_ have to catch, fillet, cook ....

Comment: While I agree that native speakers do say "she only eats fish" and mean what every other native speaker understands it to mean, I still maintain that spoken and written English _should_ follow different rules—stricter for the written. That doesn't mean that that's what actually happens in real life. Still, that languages by nature are constantly evolving shouldn't lead us to simply lie down and give up.

Comment: Don't tell me: you also allow and support the use of _they_ as a gender neutral singular pronoun... because that's "what most native speakers actually do." It's a mad, mad world.

Answer (score 0):

'Typically use only' means they usually use public transportation only and no other means of transport. While 'typically only use' means they only usually use public transportation and rarely any other mode of transportation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).