# Order of words in "...has not only been..."

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-order, correlative-conjunctions

What's the correct order of the words in "...has not only been..."?

My original sentence:

> My world **not only** has been turned inside out, but it’s also become increasingly bizarre.

One of my editors wants to change it to:

> My world has **not only** been turned inside out, but it’s also become increasingly bizarre.

Which is correct?

Comment: Might be easier with a full sentence.

Comment: There is a third option too: "has been not only .."

Comment: Your sentence begins bifurcating what *My world has* immediately after "My world has not only been." So you're setting up that your world has not only been A but B. Then you introduce a new subject and verb "it’s also become." To correct the thing, I'd want *Not only has **my world** ... but **it's** also become...*

Comment: I prefer @Yosef's variant. But there seems too me to be a rather odd pairing: radical change and becoming bizarre are closely linked. Perhaps 'Not only has my world been drastically changed: it has been changed into something bizarre.'

Comment: Well streamlined per @EdwinAshworth.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin I like the _better parallelism_ = _more streamlined_ metaphor extension, especially as the inference is that poorer parallelism is sub-optimal.

Answer (score 2):

They're both grammatical.

There's a good reason to make the change, though: the editor's version has more parallelism. Expanding the contraction in the second clause, the verbs in these clauses are "has not only been" and "has also become", so both *not only* and *also* are between the auxiliary verb and the main verb, providing grammatical parallelism. And grammatical parallelism generally makes things sound better (and often makes sentences easier to understand).

Comment: The OP's original phrasing in the first quote "but it’s also become" should be "but also has become" to be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

As @Peter says, they're all grammatical, but it does make a difference where *not, only,* and *also* go.

The normal position for a logically salient piece of machinery like these words is right **after the first auxiliary verb**, which is the auxiliary verb that's required for some rules, like Question Formation, Negative Contraction, Subject-Auxiliary Contraction, and others. So the example sentence is the best one.

However, there are problems with these words. [*Only* has a focus](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/115157/15299), and it can appear immediately before its focused constituent, or before any constituent containing the focus. The addressee can generally tell from the intonation contours what the focus is, but the reader can't, so in writing it's good practice to put *only* as close as possible to its focus.

In the case of the second sentence, *only* is sitting right before the verb phrase starting with *been* that is its focus, and also follows *not*, which is in its accustomed place right after the first auxiliary. Which is the position of *also* in the second sentence, so it increases the parallelism, as @Peter pointed out.

tl;dr your editor had it right.