# Do all variations of this sentence seem grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order

There is an interesting English sentence which is making rounds in the social media nowadays. It goes like this:

> For the following sentence, add the word "only" anywhere in this
>   sentence, and each time you get a different meaning out of the new
>   sentence.
>
> "I hit him in the eye yesterday"

So, if we try doing the above, we get following eight variations.

The Message:

1. ONLY I hit him in the eye yesterday. (No one else did.)
2. I ONLY hit him in the eye yesterday. (Did not slap him.)
3. I hit ONLY him in the eye yesterday. (I did not hit others.)
4. I hit him ONLY in the eye yesterday. (I did not hit outside the eye.)
5. I hit him in ONLY the eye yesterday. (Not other organs.)
6. I hit him in the ONLY eye yesterday. (He doesn't have another eye..)
7. I hit him in the eye ONLY yesterday. (Not today.)
8. I hit him in the eye yesterday ONLY. (Did not wait for today.)

The sentence No. 5 and 6 do not look grammatically very correct. What do you guys think? Are all of these grammatically correct or is there a problem with any/some of these?

Comment: They're all fine grammatically. For (6) one would normally say ***his** only eye*; (7) can mean "as recently as yesterday"; (8) is awkward but unambiguously means "yesterday and no other day". By the way, "what do you think" questions are designed for discussion, and are definitely frowned upon.

Comment: (4) also seems ambiguous. It can mean the same thing as (5)

Comment: I've already answered this question [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/115157/15299) and repeated it [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/55314/15299). The grammar rule is still the same; _only_ and other words of its ilk can appear **either** immediately before its focus, **or** immediately before any constituent that contains its focus.

Comment: McCawley looks excellent. And not a mention of adverbs!

Comment: Yes, all grammatical, but as someone has noted 4 and 5 seem to mean the same thing.

Comment: And there can be alternative readings. (2) 'I ONLY hit him in the eye yesterday' can mean I ONLY went and hit him in the eye yesterday (and now I find he's my new boss.) Also, this placing is often used to mean the same thing as 7, with 'only' meaning 'just' in the sense of 'as recently as' rather than 'on no other occasion'..

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Can you add your answer to an answer, please?

Answer (score 0):

4 and 5 have identical meanings, but both make sense. 6 should be written as *I hit him in **his** ONLY eye yesterday* in order to have the meaning stated (at the moment it sounds like there is only one eye in the whole world).

So yes, they all make grammatical sense insofar as they can be read and understood, but 6 doesn't really make sense idiomatically.