# "If only I" or "If I only"

Tags: word-order, only

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Correct position of “only”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/correct-position-of-only)

Should I use *only* before or after the pronoun?

> If only I had a chance
>
> If I only had a chance

Both sentences bring a lot of results and both seem to be the name of songs. Are both correct? Is there a rule for similar sentences?

Answer (score 3):

I think placement with respect to the *verb* is what matters here, not the pronoun...but the two phrases are nearly synonymous anyway. The shade of difference is that the second phrase could mean "if I had nothing but a chance".

Answer (score 1):

Either order seems OK to me when, as in the example, it is an appeal to a higher power for the thing desired.

Otherwise, 'only' should really come before the thing qualified. *I only saw him last night* (I did not speak to him)
*I saw only him last night* (No-one else)
*I saw him only last night* (that recently)

The trouble is that, in speech, we tend to emphasise the thing to which *only* relates rather than placing *only* correctly.

*I only SAW him last night*

*I only saw HIM last night*

*I only saw him LAST NIGHT*

In short notices, *only* is likely to come last: *Staff Only*.

Answer (score 0):

Your two sentences have different meanings:

> If only I had a chance

precludes others from having a chance, whereas

> If I only had a chance

implies that I don't have a chance, but that if I did I could be able to do something.