# Meaning behind "Only" position? how to use "only" properly?

Tags: adjectives, adverb-position, only, adjective-position

1. **only** I eat an apple
2. I **only** eat an apple
3. I eat **only** an apple
4. I eat an apple **only**

3 and 4 sentence are more confusing.., both are same??
please help me guys

Comment: hi @clare. [link](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/5481/264383) i saw this. still not cleared with 3 and 4. could you please explain in details

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 essentially implies that you, and you alone are the sole person who eats apples. Number 2 states that the sole food you eat is apples. Number 3 and 4 essentially mean the same thing as number 2, and that is that you only eat apples.

Comment: Hello, Jilly. This question should not be answered as it has been asked before and shows no research; Clare had already pointed this out. // You fail to distinguish count (an apple) and non-count (the foodstuff apple); admittedly OP probably didn't intend this complication. / (2) is ambiguous, with at least three possible readings.