# What is the correct way to use `only`

Tags: grammaticality, synonyms

I would like to use the word *only* in my sentences. However, I am always confused how to use it correctly. For example:

> The method of the author was *only* applied to a specific area.
>
> The method of the author considered *only* a specific type of food.

Are my sentences correct? Any help, please?

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary (eg https://ahdictionary.com/)?

Comment: Your second sentence is surreal. Did you really mean to describe a method as "food"?

Comment: @jtheletter really it is an amazing help. Thanks alot.

Comment: @ruakh, I would like to say that the method was only considered or applied to a specific type of food (to do his/her experiment)

Comment: This page should help: [Correct position of “only”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/correct-position-of-only)

Comment: It's unclear if the question is asking where to place "only" or about its meaning/usage. In both sentences, the adverb "only" is positioned in the same word order. Where is the *difference*?  The 2nd sentence makes very little sense, you changed the verb and added an indefinite article (a) and I don't see how it would be meaningful in any language.