# Is only vs only is

Tags: adverb-position, only, adjective-position

Which one is correct usage of "only" and difference between the following sentences

1. what is point of living if it is only a stuggle.
2. what is point of living if it only is a struggle.

Comment: Santosh, this question should be on ELL, not here. However, the idiom is: What is *the* point of living.

Comment: 1st - Life is a struggle only. 2nd - Only life is a struggle. 1st one is the meaningful in this context I think.

Comment: Even corrected for grammar, these are unidiomatic. "What is the point of living if it's just one long struggle?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct position of "only"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/correct-position-of-only) (+ other duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What is [the] point of living if it is [only a struggle.]

(only is part of the predicate)

2. What is [the] point of living if [it only] is a struggle.

(only is part of the noun)

The 'only' in these sentences is adding emphasis to different objects – the placement of 'only' before or after the linking verb "is" makes the difference.

In the first sentence, only is modifying that the act of living. That to live is to struggle.

In the second sentence, the claim is that living is the only thing that is a struggle. It would be understood that living is a struggle and nothing else is.  It would be the same to say "Only it is a struggle."

Comment: I wouldn't go along with all that you say. Grammatically, in 1. the focusing adverb "only" is a modifier in the noun phrase "only a struggle" (it modifies "a struggle"). In 2. "only" is a modifier in the  verb phrase "it only is a struggle". There's no difference in meaning between the two.