# only pay for or pay for only

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I’m puzzled by a couple of advertising jingles heard recently, by different companies.

Is it me, or does:

> Only pay for what you need.

mean something rather different than:

> Pay for only what you need.

?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct position of "only"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/correct-position-of-only) // Pragmatics (how people actually use the language, however much this throws up inconvenient exceptions to 'the rules') trumps the 'well-behaved' ideal many have for the language.

Comment: You should explain what you think they mean. The principle of SE is that you do a little work when asking a question: research, think, explain why you're asking, go into a bit of detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5466/correct-position-of-only#).

Technically, *Only pay for what you need* could be said to mean 'only pay for it, don't do anything else to it'. In practice, no-one would really interpret it that way.